# combining sound card and ADC (I2C)

Tags: pi-3, gpio, audio, i2c, analog-to-digital

Am thinking of using an [Audio Injector sound card](http://www.audioinjector.net/rpi-hat), which apparently has a two-channel high-precision ADC. In addition I will be needing to read two different variable resistances. One of these has two different values (zero & infinity), and the other has six different values (54 Ω, 147 Ω, 301 Ω, 562 Ω, 1037 Ω, 5057 Ω). I assume this counts as low precision. I only need to read these values a few times per second or so.

Looking at the ADS1115, it seems to be using the I2C pins (SDA & SCL), which I believe the sound card also uses.

Is it possible to use these together? If not, are there any other low-precision (8-bit?) ADC options (i.e. available extension boards)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the two systems together.

The Audio Injector sound cards share the I2C pins only for setup and mixer settings. For audio signalling, the Audio Injector sound card uses the I2S lines.

The ADC will share the I2C lines to gather ADC samples.

You should be able to share I2C lines between the cards.